# How to mvndebug in fedora

Tags: java, linux, maven, debugging, fedora

I have a problem, i need to debug a maven project using the mvndebug in fedora Linux, but the terminal does not recognize the mvndebug command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora's command line is case sensitive, and I believe the command is `mvnDebug`, with a capital D.  Try that.

Does `mvn` work?  If not, you need to `sudo yum install maven2` to install it.

Answer (score 1):

The maven debug tool is installed as part of maven's package (`yum install maven`). Note, however, it's called `mvnDebug`, with a capital D.

Comment: Thank you very much , it worked.  I have no reputation enough to 'this answer is useful'